# Can I use a Method or Class from a later API on an older platform?

Tags: java, android, video, mp4

This is my first question, so please be gentle!

I use Android Studio 3.1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04

I would like to extract a single frame from a short (<5 seconds) mp4 on tablets and phones.
I need the frame closest to an exact time NOT the **key**-frame closest to that time.
My research has led me to MediaMetadataRetriever to do this.

BUT the getFrameAtTime(time, OPTION_CLOSEST) method only works properly from API 27 (before that, it returns the nearest key-frame, not the nearest frame). But I would like to make my app run on API 21 (for market penetration reasons).

How can I make MediaMetadataRetriever.getFrameAtTime(time, OPTION_CLOSEST) from API 27 available to my application on a device running API 21?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Probably by implementing such feature yourself ?

Comment: @kulatamicuda: please could you give me some pointers for how I go about doing that please?